# Check whether a command executed successfully WITHOUT system functions using fork()

Tags: c++, shell, fork

fork() creates a new process by duplicating the calling process in the separate memory space. The execution of the forked process can be checked by checking the pid_t returned value by fork() function.
I used fork() to create some concurrent processes from a single parent. These processes are commands in a shell that no need to be executed.
I'm wondering how I can check whether the command is a valid command that can be executed or not without using the system functions and/or execute them.

```
         #include <iostream>
         #include <unistd.h>
         #include <string>

          int main(){

          std::string command = "/bin/ls";
          //std::string invalidCommand = "/bin/123"; 
          pid_t pid = fork();
          if(pid == -1 || `here I want to check if the command is executable without execution`){
            std::cout << "Error in forking or Command is not executable" << std::endl;
          }
          else if (pid == 0){
            std::cout << "Process has been forked and valid to execute" << std::endl;
          }
         return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `fork()` failing has nothing to do with running a command.

Comment: `system` or `popen` is about it. Otherwise, there is no other built-in interface with the shell from within C.

Comment: `command -v /bin/ls`. There are many ways to do this. For your use case, you just need to check if the file exists and is executable. Another command to do this is: `test -x /bin/ls`. If you want, you can translate that to code

Answer (score 1):

> These processes are commands in a shell that no need to be executed.

I don't fully understand what you want to say with this sentence. However, I think you are not aware how `fork()` works and how `system()` is related to `fork()`:

As you already found out, `fork()` duplicates a running process; this means that the program is now running twice and all variables exist twice (just like if you run your program twice).

`system()` internally uses `fork()` to create a copy of the process; in the newly created process it uses one of the `exec()` variants (such as `execvp()`) to replace the program in the new process by another program.

Then it uses one of the `wait()` variants (such as `waitpid()`) to wait for the new process to finish:

```
fflush(stdout);
fflush(stderr);
int newpid = fork();
if(newpid == 0)
{
    execlp("ls", "ls", "./subdirectory", NULL);
    std::cerr << "Could not start \"ls\".\n";
    fflush(stderr);
    _exit(1);
}
if(newpid < 0)
{
    std::cerr << "Not enough memory.\n";
}
else
{
    int code;
    waitpid(newpid, &code, 0);
    if(code == 0) std::cout << "\"ls\" was successful.";
    else std::cout << "\"ls\" was not successful.";
}
```

If you want to have "special" behaviour (such as re-directing `stdout` to a file), you typically don't use the `system()` function but you will implement the program the way it is shown above.

> I'm wondering how I can check whether the command is a valid command ...

Without running the program it is nearly impossible to find out if some command is executable:

It is possible to find out if a program with some name (e.g. `"/usr/bin/ls"`) is existing and marked as executable using the `access()` function (this is what `command -v` or `test -x` do).

However, this test will not detect if a file mistakenly has the `x` flag set although the file is a document file and not a program. (This is often the case for files on Windows-formatted media.)

If `wait()` returns the value passed to the `_exit()` function, it is also difficult to check if the reason is that `exec()` failed (this means that the program could not be executed) or if the program that has been started returned the same code that we use in our `_exit()` function.

You can send some information from the new process to the original process if the `exec()` function has returned. The `exec()` function will never return on success. However, sending this information is not that easy: Just setting a variable will not work:

```
int ls_failed = 0;
int pid = fork();
if(pid == 0)
{
    execlp("ls", "ls", "./subdirectory", NULL);
    ls_failed = 1;
    _exit(1);
}
wait(pid, NULL, 0);
if(ls_failed > 0) std::cout << "Starting \"ls\" failed.";
```

The two processes behave like you started the programs twice; therefore both processes have their own variables, so the variable `ls_failed` in the newly started process is not identical to the variable `ls_failed` in the original process.

> ```
> std::cout << ...
> ```

Please note that `std::cout` probably internally performs an `fwrite(...,stdout)`. This function will not write directly to the terminal but it will write to some buffer. When the buffer is full, all data is written at once.

When calling `fork()` the buffer is duplicated; when using `_exit()` or `exec()`, the data in the buffer is lost.

This may lead to weird effects:

```
std::cout << "We are doing some fork() now.";
int pid = fork();
if(pid == 0)
{
    std::cout << "\nNow the child process is running().";
    _exit(0);
}
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
std::cout << "\nThe child process has finished.\n";
```

Depending on the buffer size we could get the following output:

```
We are doing some fork() now.
Now the chi ng some fork() now.
The child process has finished.
```

Therefore, we should perform a `fflush(stdout)` and a `fflush(stderr)` before using `fork()`, an `exec()` variant or `_exit()` unless you know that the corresponding buffer (`stdout` for `std::cout` and `stderr` for `std::cin`) is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the system call `wait` and check the return value of the command that you attempted to execute, other than that `fork` would really help you. try reading the man page of `wait`.

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html